# Is there a way to cast Template's Type to shared_ptr<T>?

Tags: templates, c++11, casting, smart-pointers

Recently, I am working for a school's assignment which is about to construct a very simple polynomial expression by using class and object.
We don't have to construct parse function , so to construct an normal expression there's a lot codes needed to write and very hard to discern when there's many codes. So I thought that maybe this is a good context to try C++ template ( I'm really a fresh man for C++, so I am not so experienced for template and not sure if in this condition I could use it.)
as an example, I need to implement OperatorPlus whose declaration correspondant is`std::shared<Expression> OperateurPlus(std::shared<Expression>, std::shared<Expression>)`. I want to create `template<typename T, typename M> std::shared<Expression> plus(T lhs, M rhs)` wrapper to response different passed-in parameters. And I follow the where clause in another language to add the type limitation by utilizing `enable_if`. So the code is like this:

```
template<typename T, typename M,
        typename = std::enable_if<(
                                   std::is_same<unsigned int, T>::value ||
                                   std::is_same<char, T>::value ||
                                   std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<Expression>, T>::value) &&
        ( std::is_same<unsigned int, M>::value ||
         std::is_same<std::shared_ptr<Expression>, M>::value ||
         std::is_same<char, M>::value)>
        >
        std::shared_ptr<Expression> plus(T lhs, M rhs){
            std::shared_ptr<Expression> t_lhs, t_rhs;
            if (std::is_same<T, uint>::value) t_lhs = Nombre::create(uint(lhs));
            if (std::is_same<T, char>::value) t_lhs = std::shared_ptr<Expression>(new Variable(char(lhs)));
            if (std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<Expression>>::value) t_lhs = (std::shared_ptr<Expression>)(lhs);

            if (std::is_same<M, uint>::value) t_rhs = Nombre::create(uint(rhs));
            if (std::is_same<M, char>::value) t_rhs = std::shared_ptr<Expression>(new Variable(char(rhs)));
            if (std::is_same<M, std::shared_ptr<Expression>>::value) t_rhs = (std::shared_ptr<Expression>)(rhs);
            return std::shared_ptr<Expression>(new OperateurPlus(t_lhs, t_rhs));
        }
```

and my question is `(std::shared_ptr<Expression>)(lhs)` this part. I used a c-style casting because I don't how to realize this casting operation. IDE told my std::shared_ptr is not a pointer or reference if I tried static_cast> and it think lhs is unsigned int type.
 So if I just follow the compile's hints, my question is

1. how to cast a template's Type to std::shared_ptr?  or
2. If is it possible to pass a std::shared_ptr as a template parameter?

Comment: You could create helper functions, something like `auto make_expression(const std::shared_ptr<Expression>& expr) { return expr; }` (which does nothing if it's already an expression), and additional overloads which promote integers to `Expression`s.

Comment: For a shared pointer `std::shared_ptr<Expression> ptr`, you can statically cast using `std::static_pointer_cast<Expression>(ptr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of a template function must be entirely compilable for a given template instantiation. Even if one of those `if` statements will never be visited, the condition still needs to be syntactically valid for the appropriate types.

Having a single function for this is the wrong approach. One possible solution would be to create an overloaded function to get a `std::shared_ptr` from any of your required sources, then use that function to achieve the desired genericicity.

```
using ExpPtr = std::shared_ptr<Expression>; //for brevity

ExpPtr convertToExp (ExpPtr e) {
    return e;
}

ExpPtr convertToExp (unsigned int i) {
    return Nombre::create(i);
}

ExpPtr convertToExp (char c) {
    return std::make_shared<Variable>(c);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
ExpPtr plus (T lhs, U rhs) {
    auto lhsExp = convertToExp(lhs);
    auto rhsExp = convertToExp(rhs);
    return std::make_shared<OperateurPlus>(lhsExp, rhsExp);
}
```

I don't think all the SFINAE is necessary. This will hard-fail if there isn't a valid call to `convertToExp` for `T` or `U`.

I didn't try to compile this as you didn't supply an MVCE, so there might be some mistakes.

---

If you really want the SFINAE to prevent implicit conversions in the `convertToExp` calls, you could do it in a cleaner way like this:

```
template<typename... Conds>
struct or_ : std::false_type {};

template<typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct or_<Cond, Conds...>
        : std::conditional_t<Cond::value, std::true_type,
        or_<Conds...>> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using is_one_of = or_<std::is_same<T,Ts>...>;

template <typename T>
using is_valid_exp_source = 
    is_one_of<T, char, unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<Expression>>;

template <typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<is_valid_exp_source<T>::value && is_valid_exp_source<U>::value, 
                 ExpPtr> 
plus (T lhs, U rhs) {
    auto lhsExp = convertToExp(lhs);
    auto rhsExp = convertToExp(rhs);
    return std::make_shared<OperateurPlus>(lhsExp, rhsExp);
}
```